# PowerShell and Windows Terminal: how to apply IntelliSense suggestion?

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

Using Windows Terminal (1.15.3465.0) and PowerShell (7.3.2) I get autocomplete suggestion, like in the picture below (`ed255196 -C "<comment>"` is suggested completion).

However, I am not able to apply that suggestion. I tried <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and a few different combinations but none of these works.

[image]

How can I apply that suggestion?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### How do I apply an IntelliSense suggestion?

You need to use the right arrow key <kbd>-></kbd>:

> **Key Bindings for Predictions**
>
> Key bindings control cursor movement and additional features within
> the prediction. To support users running Predictive IntelliSense on
> multiple platforms, key bindings are user-settable from the command
> line or your profile script.
>
> `PSReadLine` contains functions to navigate and accept predictions. As
> an example, to accept a displayed prediction, `PSReadLine` contains
> functions:
>
> ```
> `AcceptSuggestion` – Accept the current inline suggestion
> `AcceptNextSuggestionWord` – Accept the next word of the inline suggestion
> ```
>
> `AcceptSuggestion` is built within `ForwardChar`, which by default is
> bound to <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> accepts
> an inline suggestion when the cursor is at the end of the current
> line.

Source: [Announcing PSReadLine 2.1+ with Predictive IntelliSense - PowerShell Team](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/)

Comment: Whoa! That's what I was looking for, thanks!